# postgresql tables deleted misteriously

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

It is the second day that I am encountering a strange thing: my tables in a postresql DB have all been deleted.
I am the only one who has access to that system, so it can pretty much rule out that another user has deleted them.

My question is: how can this be? And how can I find out what happened?

I did check the log file, but the only relevant thing I found there was something like:

`2017-04-18 22:28:15 BST STATEMENT:  drop schema public cascade`

Who or what would issues such a command `drop schema public cascade`? And for what reason?

Any hints are appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: restrict connections in hba.conf - it will give you idea if your friend has access to shell

Comment: Postgres will not run that statement on it's own. It mus be your application.

Comment: I've voted to close simply because it's obvious that there isn't enough information to diagnose the problem. Something is happening, and it's not happening without a reason and only you can figure out that reason or provide information.

Comment: @VaoTsun: ok, did that now. I am also adjusting my logging config.

Comment: next thing I'd do is `alter user UNAME nosuperuser` to all superusers on the system, check the owner of the public schema and change the password, save hba.conf last modification time or hash to see if it changes

Comment: @VaoTsun: I figured out the problem. First of all postres was listening to all interfaces, second some weak passwords where used. I have changed these, the server is only listening on local host and I have also set new secure passwords for all relevant users. The server is basically not accessible from the outside any more. Thanks for your hints.

Comment: there is no default password in postgres. listening on star is ok. good luck